# NO reconoce el nombre del storyboard swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode

Estoy tratando de pasar a otro viewcontroller por medio de modal, con este procedimiento:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"RadiosPVSViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

El problema es que me tira un error que no reconoce el nombre del StoryBoard y esta correcto. (Main.storyboard).

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: al parecer debes castear el controller, ejemplo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776929/swift-3-xcode-8-instantiate-view-controller-is-not-working

Comment: Gracias excelente me funcionó